# Why is a tweet of mine no longer showing on hashtag pages?

Tags: twitter

I tweeted a tweet and then checked the hashtag pages for it and saw it there. On the next day - it's only on one of them. And if I'm not logged in - it's not shown there either. Why?

Comment: Did you filter by Live or Top? If you didn't get a lot of hearts or retweets it's going to drop off

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise I see that it was "top". I tried "live" and I can see it. Thank you. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because the default filter/sort on Twitter search is "Top" and your tweet may not have enough faves/hearts and/or retweets to bring it up to the top of the listings.

It should show if you sort by "Live" which would show them chronologically (backward - newest at top) and not based on popularity (as weighted by the retweets and favourites/hearts mentioned).